# Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 When applying textures with Three.js in WebGL

Tags: javascript, jquery, webgl, three.js

i am following [this tutorial](http://aerotwist.com/lab/creating-particles-with-three-js/) on getting started with webGL and three.js. My problem is when adding the line `map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/particle.png"),` Chrome raises  `Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18.`

I understand this is due to cross domain referencing but i am serving this from a vm with a LAMP setup so how can it be a cross reference? I can make it work by doing `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on the host and then open http://localhost:8000/Particles.html in chrome but this solution is useless if it only works with a local server.

How can make it work so the webserver can actually server the page correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've played with three.js a bit, but I'm afraid I'm not great with JavaScript.

Still, I think you should give [Max Novakovic's getImageData API](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/).
If it helps, there's a short post on the [disturb media blog](http://www.disturbmedia.com/blog/post/cross-domain-getimagedata-api-using-google-app-engine/) about it.

Comment: It could be a way to get around the problem but with that script my app would be depend on the availability of the server rerouting the images. However i dont understand why this error appears in the first place when it is hosted on a server in the vm!?

Answer (score 0):

It should work when hosted on a web server and the images are fetched from the same domain (as you can see from the python -m SimpleHTTPServer case). I don't know what's going on with the VM server, is it doing some sort of virtual host redirects? (As in: web page requests http://foobar/image.png, server 302 redirects to http://cdn/image.png)

If you have a test case somewhere, I can take a look.